# Does the Saber-Toothed Tiger have Darkvision?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, errata

I noticed that the regular Tiger received Darkvision, so the question arises — does the Saber Toothed Tiger actually have Darkvision also? Is this a confirmed accidental omission by the designers?

Answer (score 4):

As of April 2017, the [errata for the Monster Manual](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PH-Errata.pdf) includes no correction to the Saber-toothed Tiger's lack of darkvision.

Comment: For what it's worth this is still the case as of the [2018 errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/MM-Errata.pdf).